# Is there any possible way to use firebase database only for real time messaging and store the data on own server

Tags: php, android, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I am trying to build a chat app using android, firebase, php and MySQL but I can't afford to store all the messages on firebase database yet. So, I like to use it just for real time chatting while two users are interacting each other and then delete all the chat log on the firebase and store it on my own database, so that I can show the messages from the previous conversations to the users.

So the problem is that how will I be able to show the previous messages to the user. Here are the logic I can figure out

1) I will upload all the old messages to the firebase database when two users start to interact each other and show all the old and new conversation in the recyclerview android.

But this could become trouble when thousands of users start to interact each other at the same time as we need to upload bulk amount of data to the firebase.

2) Get all the old conversations from my own server and create new node on firebase database then show all of them together again in a recycler view.

But it will be very painful to show the old and new messages in a single recyclerview from two different data sources and can't do realtime sync.

Is there any possible way I could have done and I would be much appreciated if you guys started discussing about this topic.

P.S : I will use firebase pay service later when I can afford.

Comment: Are you really ready for this extra complication, even before you've made your chat application? Dealing with all the synchronization issues between firebase, MySQL and your clients is going to be a nightmare. I would suggest to choose one database to start with, use an abstracted database layer, and try to build a working chat app first. If people actually want to use it, and it gets popular, it is time to think about scaling problems. Remember that chat apps don't need super low response times. Most of the time people are reading, thinking and typing anyway.

Comment: Another, completely unthinkable, option is to connect users directly, without receiving, sending,  and storing any messages from, to, and on a central database. Each user could have its own little database, locally. The central server is then only used to find other users.

Comment: yup, I just realized it would be the best to start with firebase database first.

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).